# Can't load ubuntu. I see grub>

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

I tried to install ubuntu desktop 18.04 on laptop Acer Aspire ES 15.
Bios on this laptop don't have a legacy mode.
As I understood ubuntu was installed but can't start.
If I try to start ubuntu on Laptop i see string:
grub>

How can I fix it? Version of grub is 2.02